# Alexa Flash Briefing API with SSML

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I have created a simple flash briefing skill that reads from a rss feed. However it is pronouncing the name of the company wrong. I have reviewed the SSML page on the amazon developer site, but i do not see a way to get to the js that runs the skill. Is there any way to edit the js behind the skill if I am using the default API? Is there another solution short of writing a standalone skill?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that yet. SSML is allowed in the Feed content only.

However you can up-vote the [idea](https://alexa.uservoice.com/forums/906892-alexa-skills-developer-voice-and-vote/suggestions/33346060-allow-flash-briefings-to-use-ssml), you are not the first one who faces this issue.